# How isthe transparency of glass explained in physics?

Tags: optics, condensed-matter, material-science

I would like a rigorous explanation: a theory and model which describes glass as well as iron, and see why one of them is transparent; a detailed mathematical computation or a detailed reference.

And, from this model, trivially one has to be able to calculate the intensity of the partial reflection of light from the glass as a function of its thickness.

Richard Feynman has answered a somehow popular answer to this question in his little QED book. I would like to see detailed mathematical calculations which conclude this fact from rigorous QED theory.

Comment: Wood (cellulose) is transparent. It just has lots of surfaces. Like snow.

Comment: I changed wood by iron and having less information about materials I hope it does not transparent.

Comment: Your question is a bit difficult to read. Please add some more detail, so we can provide the best possible answer

Comment: I see no good reason for either the quantum-field-theory of quantum-electrodynamics tags. Given the optical properties of a material (which is a solid state physics problem) the calculation is moderately straightforward.

Comment: Metals are fundamentally different because they’re conductors. Electric fields *can’t* exist in a conductor (for any appreciable amount of time) because the free-moving electrons will always move to cancel the field, and since light is an electromagnetic wave it *can’t* enter conductors, and so it is reflected. You should probably narrow your focus to insulators.

Comment: I hope answers in that contexts because Feynman have given a somehow popular answer to this question in this little QED book based on QED. @JonCuster

Comment: @RyanFranz - yet metals aren’t perfect conductors, so light most certainly can penetrate some distance, excite plasmons, and other things like that.

Comment: @JonCuster - I am aware, my comment was just for practical purposes (except for plasmons... I’m interested now). Anyways, there’s obviously a tremendous difference between conducting and non-conducting transparencies, and I could be wrong, but usually it is more desirable to have a model that is specific and highly detailed than one that is all-inclusive at the cost of detail.

Comment: This isn't a question.  This is a work request, with significant deliverables.

Comment: @moshtaba How much do you know about QED?

Comment: The question is too broad and there is a clear lack of research. You need solid state physics, such as band theory, local density approximation, Drude model, Hubbard model.

Answer (score 3):

While the theory that explains all of this is quantum mechanics, the derivations you want are not trivial at all. The examples you gave are completely different types of materials with completely different approaches being used in solid state physics to describe them via QM. You should be able to find descriptions in every good book on solid state physics.

A few hints at a better understanding of the topic:
Glass is transparent in the visible part of the spectrum. However: UV light has a hard time passing glass. That's why one can't get a sunburn below glass. This means that glass is only transparent from our perspective. At the same time radio waves can easily penetrate walls that visible light cannot. So glass just happens to be transparent to us, while e.g. muscle tissue would be transparent to some hypothetical creature being sensible to x-rays. If you look at the complete spectrum, every material is transparent at some wavelengths and not at others. Using QM you can compute which material is transparent at which wavelengths.

EDIT: While QED may be more fundamental than QM, as well as somewhat more suitable b/c one has to work w/ many particle systems, the QM derivations are enough for qualitative descriptions as relativistic effects aren't of much interest here and in the non-relativistic limit QED gives QM w/ minimal substitution.